# Will custom keyboard be available in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, apple-watch

I'd like to ask to those who are currently developing an application for Apple Watch, about:

Is it possible that developers implement any type of custom input methods, like custom keyboards in iOS 8? I know that Apple will be supporting voice recognition using Siri, but never actually heard of whether they are supports custom keyboards or APIs to develop them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is not enough space for a full keyboard. However, I created my own number pad using individual buttons. It works and I can easily enter a number with it.